# how can I use mechanize python in java

Tags: java, mechanize

I have a question about mechanize for java, I downloaded from http://gistlabs.com/software/mechanize-for-java/ and I can't find the jar because I want to import in my java project, please help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it from the central maven repository:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cmechanize

Comment: thanks, the url shows 10 options, what would you recommend to download,is the last version in Release Candidate?

Comment: I'd give a try to the 2.0-RC1

Answer (score 0):

You can include their project in your build-path for your project, instead of adding jars. 
If you are using eclipse:
Properties--> Java Build Path --> Projects Tab --> Add.

Or if you want to use maven, you can add the dependency.

Find more information on their github on the bottom of read me.

Comment: thanks, but I'm using netbeans, I found the jar in the link http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cmechanize